# Set the sum of listboxitems to a textblock

Tags: wpf, listbox, textblock

I have a listbox in which I have stored domain objects. These objects have a property price. Now I would like to bind the content of a textblock to the sum of the priceproperties of the items in my listbox. What is the simpelest way to do this? I'm not working with a MVVM.

Sean

Comment: textblock placed inside the listboxitems template or outside of the listbox?

Comment: outside the listbox...